# Trouble importing numpy

Tags: python, numpy, import

I want to import numpy.  I do not have it as a module so I attempted to download it as a .whl file.  I successfully downloaded it to my computer but am having trouble with installing into python 3.7.

I know I have to install numpy onto my computer and then Python.  I downloaded the .whl file but am having trouble transferring it into my cmd prompt.

> > > import numpy as np
> > >       Traceback (most recent call last):
> > >         File "stdin", line 1, in module
> > >       ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'numpy'

I want to "import numpy as np" without errors

Comment: You should be using `pip` to install/manage your packages.

Comment: open a console, and type `pip install numpy`

Comment: >>> pip install numpy
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    pip install numpy
              ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found that for python 3 on windows,

```
py -m pip install numpy
```

works.

On Linux it's

```
python3 -m pip install numpy.
```

This would be entered into command prompt on windows, or terminal on Linux.

Furthermore, this will only work if you have python on your path. On windows you should be able to specify this when installing, on Linux it should be like this by default.

**EDIT:**

When installing, you should see this:

[image: add python to path]

You should check "add python to path" and click "Install now" since it will install pip for you

[image: "pip"]

I actually installed python without checking the "add python to path" and I can call it from CMD with `py`. So, if you can call it without the full path, then you are fine.

If you don't have pip....

Go to https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py and either downloaded it, or copy and paste it into a python file. Run this file and pip should be installed. On windows you can also go to Control panel>Programs>Programs and Features and select python and click "Change". This should give you

[image: install pip]

Comment: I got an error saying 'invalid syntax', pointing to pip.  I think my problem lays with the path, is there an easy way to check if python is on my path?

Comment: What os are you using? Also, can you show the error message? If you can type py, or python3 or python or py3 or someother variation in cmd or terminal and see this https://imgur.com/OKplfjq.png , then you should be able to use pip.

Comment: Okay, i reinstalled and checked off add py 3.7 path!

Comment: I tired "pip3 install numpy" and got back "Syntax Error: Invalid Syntax"

Comment: Are you doing this in idle

Comment: Its got to be in cmd for windows or bash terminal for linux

Comment: I'm doing this in cmd... I entered 'py' and it gave me the appropriate response

Comment: This should download it automatically and install without you doing anything.

Comment: Ok  what happens if you type py -m pip --version or py pip --version. If you see something like pip 18.1 from c://....... then pip is installed. Otherwise pip probably is not installed

Comment: Thanks! Your a gentleperson and a scholar :)

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to download and manage modules is using python's built-in `pip` command.

`pip install numpy` will install numpy in your site-packages directory, where it needs to be to use it with Python 2

`pip3 install numpy` will do the same thing for Python 3

Answer (score 0):

try Anaconda [home](https://www.anaconda.com/), it wil help you save a lot of time dealing with these errors.
if u dont't want to use it, try

```
pip install numpy
```

or

```
pip3 install numpy
```

like other answers.

Comment: >>> pip install numpy  
  File "<stdin>", line 1  
    pip install numpy  
              ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax